# How is bc different from dc?

Tags: command-line, bc, calculator

What are the differences between `dc` and `bc` calculators?

When should I use `dc` and when `bc`?

Comment: I use `expr` very often for simple calculations on the command line and in scripts.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`dc` is a very archaic tool and somewhat older than `bc`. To quote the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29):

> It is one of the oldest Unix utilities, predating even the invention of the C programming language; like other utilities of that vintage, it has a powerful set of features but an extremely terse syntax.

The syntax is a reverse polish notation, which basically means that the arguments (ie numbers) come first followed by the operator. A basic example of the `dc` usage is:

```
echo '3 4 * p' | dc
```

Where the `p` is required to print the result of the calculation. `bc` on the other hand uses the more familiar infix notation and thus is more intuitive to use. Here is an example of `bc` usage:

```
echo '3 * 4' | bc
```

#### Which one to use?

`bc` is standardised by POSIX and so is probably the more portable of the two (at least on modern systems). If you are doing manual calculator work then it is definitely the choice (unless you are somewhat of a masochist). `dc` can still have its uses though, here is a case where the reverse polish notation comes in handy. Imagine you have a program which outputs a stream of numbers that you want to total up, eg:

```
23
7
90
74
29
```

To do this with `dc` is very simple (at least with modern implementations where each operator can take more than two numbers) since you only have to append a `+p` to the stream, eg:

```
{ gen_nums; echo +p } | dc
```

But with `bc` it is more complex since we not only need to put a `+` *between* each number and make sure everything is on the same line, but also make sure there is a newline at the end:

```
{ gen_nums | sed '$ !s/$/+/' | tr -d '\n'; echo; } | bc
```

Comment: You've turned the `gen_nums` example horribly complex using `bc`.  It could be simplified to: `gen_nums | paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: Fun fact: Traditionally `bc` was only a front end tool that compiled the `bc` notation to the notation of `dc` and piped that into `dc` to get the result. On FreeBSD there is still the `-c` flag for `bc` with which you can still compile to the `dc` notation`. For example `echo '3 * 4' | bc` is equal to `echo '3 * 4' | bc -c | dc`. See the http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc and http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bc&sektion=1

Comment: Hmm, which `dc` are you using?  On Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X, the `+` operator always operates on exactly two values off the stack

Comment: The correct example of `dc` usage: `gen_nums_nonnegative | dc -e '0 0 [+?z1<m]dsmxp'`. This script for `dc` reads and adds numbers one by one in loop and then prints the result. See the [note](//stackoverflow.com/a/453290/1300170) regarding negative numbers.

Comment: @devnull I for one almost never remember that `paste` exists, and I have been using *nix for over a decade now.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens Interesting, on macOS `bc -c` does something weird and different (and the `-c` flag is undocumented). If I try to pipe it into `dc`, I get a bunch of errors (and the output without piping into `dc` is the very cryptic `@iK3:K4:*W@r\n@i`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph What is the output of `bc --version`?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens 1.0.6. And `dc` gives me: `dc (GNU bc 1.06) 1.3` — which is weird: why would dc be built on top of bc (rather than the other way round)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph because GNU only has `bc` and it looks like OSX uses GNU `bc` and maybe uses a wrapper or links to `bc` to implement `dc`.  Sadly I can't find the man pages of `bc` and `dc` for OSX online, to verify this.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens The manpages don’t mention anything along these lines, apart from both claiming to be the GNU versions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph simple anwser. `bc` and `dc` are packaged together under GNU. So when you download the sources for GNU `bc` you get `dc` as well, but they seam to have different verions and only the `bc` version number is referenced when downloading.

Comment: FWIW, the `-c` option for GNU `bc` does dump the bytecode it generates, but as the docs for GNU `bc` say: "Since the POSIX document does not specify how bc must be implemented, this version does not use the historical method of having bc be a compiler for the dc calculator. This version has a single executable that both compiles the language and runs the resulting `byte code'. The byte code is not the dc language."

Comment: What is `gen_nums` referring to?

Comment: @Diagon, just supposed to be a placeholder for something generating a stream of numbers. If you want to test the examples, you could use something like `seq -s ' ' 1 10`.

Comment: Real UNIX bc is actually a preprocessor for dc(1), which it invokes automatically, unless the -c (compile only) option is present. If you invoke bc with the flag -c it will spit out dc commands to the standard output

Answer (score 10):

A basic difference between the two is that `dc` uses the [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).  It requires explicit commands even in order to produce an output.

You might add two integers in `bc` by saying:

```
bc <<< "2+4"
```

and it would produce `6` on a line by itself.  However, in `dc` you'd need to say:

```
dc <<< "2 4 +p"
```

You can also do much fun stuff using `dc`, e.g. refer to my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22619/8560) for producing

```
Hello World!
```

using `dc`.

> dc<<<"8 9*P101P108P108P111P4 8*P81 6+P111P114P108P100P33P"

Comment: "Bc was written as a front-end to Dc"

Answer (score 3):

`dc` is a calculator whereas `bc` is an actual language. See their man pages.

*dc*

> dc  is a reverse-polish desk calculator which supports unlimited precision arithmetic.  It also allows you to define and call macros.  Normally dc reads from the standard input; if any command arguments are given to it, they are filenames, and dc reads and  executes  the  contents of the files before reading from standard input.  All normal output is to standard output; all error output is to standard error.

*bc*

> bc  is  a  language that supports arbitrary precision numbers with interactive execution of statements.  There are some similarities in the syntax to the C programming language.  A standard math library is available by command line option. If  requested,  the  math  library  is defined  before  processing  any  files. bc  starts by processing code from all the files listed on the command line in the order listed. After all files have been processed, bc reads from the standard input.  All code is executed as it is read.  (If a file contains a  command to halt the processor, bc will never read from the standard input.)

It really depends on what you're ultimately wanting to do mathematically. Some operations aren't possible using `dc`. I've used both over the years in addition to several other command-line calculator tools. See "[Command line expression solver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105111/command-line-expression-solver/)" for some additional examples.

Comment: Thanks, one more question: how is `bc` command and its language used in practice nowadays?

Comment: @REACHUS - I'm not sure I understand what you're asking? Due to `dc` being a reverse polish notation calculator and since I've always used HP reverse polish notation calculators I actually prefer using `dc` to `bc` but I would say they're both still used anytime you need to perform a complex mathematical calculation. I often use them to convert numbers b/w base 10 to base 16 and base 2. But have used them to tally columns in tabular data as well from within an AWK script.

Comment: `bc` was a *language* in the sense that it made `dc` human-friendly - not that it was more powerful. These days the apps share libs, but `bc` was called a *language* and `dc` a *calculator* because `dc` did math and `bc` spoke math - to `dc`. [Here's an older `man` page](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/vol2/dc): *A language called `BC` [1] has been developed which accepts
programs written in higher-level
 languages and compiles output which is
interpreted by DC.
Some of the commands described below were designed
for the compiler interface and are not easy for a human user
to manipulate.*

Comment: I claim `dc` is also a language.  e.g. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47921/11259

Comment: @DigitalTrauma To argue that it isn't a language would be absurd since it has a lexer and parser. But to argue it's human readable, given that example, would be absurd. I mean... damn.

Comment: @ParthianShot Agreed.  My reading of *"dc is a calculator whereas bc is an actual language"* is that slm is implying that dc is not a language, which I am disagreeing with.  But I might just be reading into the answer wrong...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma - based on the wikipedia page's descriptions, dc is described as a calculator. Those are excerpts from the 2 pages, not my own words. I was simply echoing their sentiments. But it's a point that I would agree w/. The big problem is the blurring of the lines b/w "what is a calculator" and what is not.

Comment: @slm IMO `dc` is a calculator *and* a language - as is `bc` - there is no distinction between the two in this regard.  The `bc` language just happens to be more readable (and writeable).

Comment: `dc` is like brainfuck but a version that was intended to be somewhat legible to a mathematician who worked on a PDP-7 in the 1960s. Still a language.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion and in as few words as possible,
GNU dc differs from GNU bc in 3 ways:

1) If bc's math library is out of concern, to save as many keystrokes as possible (in Jan Łukasiewicz's words: a parenthesis-free notation) when doing elementary arithmetic, to concentrate more on the essentials and to avoid distractions.

2) In Microsoft Windows 7's command line, GNU dc consumes less memory (~ 320K) than GNU bc does (~ 360K).

3) Much granular control in GNU dc than in GNU bc, for example, stack and register commands are absent from GNU bc.

Version 1.07.1 win32 for both is at https://embedeo.org/ws/command_line/bc_dc_calculator_windows/